# Pass parameter to Call method in Java.util.Concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

i am new to the high level Java.util.Concurrent package , what i am trying to do is read multiple text files at the same time using a thread pool. I need a way to pass the file name as an argument to my implementation of the call method .

Something like this :

```
public String call (String param)
```

If there is another way to achieve this i will appreciate your help.

Comment: Side comment: what you are doing is I/O bound rather than CPU bound and using multiple threads is unlikely to improve performance. It is actually probably going to be detrimental.

Comment: each thread will carry much more CPU processing than just reading files

Comment: What you want is basically a function. Java cannot easily model functions as first-class citizens, at least syntactically. Languages that have better support for functional programming may be of interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When implementing the `Runnable` interface, add your parameter as a member of the class. And add an initialization of this member in the constructor. Than use it from the run method.

For example:

```
class ConcurrentFileReader implements Runnable{
   String fileName;

   public ConcurrentFileReader(String fileName){ 
       this.fileName = fileName; 
   }

   public void run(){
       File f = new File(fileName);
      // whatever
   }
}
```

This pattern is known as a "Method Object"